# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotisoft/entrybean

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish, ejb

I'mmaking a project wherein I use a servlet and call an EJB through it.

- package name is kotisoft
- the bean name is entrybean
- interface name entrybeanLocal

My servlet code is :

```
public class reportthis extends HttpServlet {

  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
    // Context jndiContext = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
    // InitialContext ic=new InitialContext();
    // entrybean = (entrybean)ic.lookup("java:global/KotiSoft-ejb/entrybean");

    /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */

    String jindiName = entrybean.class.getName();
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
    entrybean entrybean;
    entrybean = (entrybean) ctx.lookup(jindiName);

    String name,emailid,model,problem;
    name=request.getParameter("Name");
    emailid=request.getParameter("Emailid");
    model=request.getParameter("Model");
    problem=request.getParameter("Problem");
    Ticket ticket=new Ticket(); 
    ticket.setEmailid(emailid);
    ticket.setModel(model);
    ticket.setName(name);
    ticket.setProblem(problem);
    ***entrybean.addTicket(ticket);***...
```

The starred code is where the exception is being thrown.

Glassfish server log is:

```
INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [KotiSoft-war] at [/KotiSoft-war]
INFO: KotiSoft-war was successfully deployed in 198 milliseconds.
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[reportthis]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet reportthis threw exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotisoft/entrybean
    at com.kotisoft.reportthis.processRequest(reportthis.java:47)
    at com.kotisoft.reportthis.doPost(reportthis.java:103)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotisoft.entrybean
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
    ... 28 more
```

I have all the imports done, my EJB works fine, server is running good. I also added the class folders to my WAR but no use.

Comment: First of all, classnames in Java should always start with an Uppercase letter. Please post the code for entrybean. Why do you do the context lookup manually? You can just add the entrybean as class variable and annotate it with `@EJB` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it !!

i added a glass fish deployment descriptor

and in that i added the ejb n gave it a jndi name

also my entry bean declaration in the servlet shud hav been entrybeanLocal instead of just entry bean